# Always getting Unauthorize error(401) in c2dm android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

Actually,i have used ramachandru6@gmail.com as a "sender id" in my app and that same id and same password used for getting authentication tocken.but still am getting 401 error.
i have spent more than two days.please any one guide me.what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN GCM there is nothing like using id and password for authentication. When you set up your app in GCM it will give one server side token. Use that as a key

Comment: but am using c2dm in android!please give any suggestion

Comment: Switch to new GCM. Google is strongly insisting to move to GCM. So it would be nice to follow Google's Advice :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html   And download updates of ADT it will have Extras-> Google Cloud Messaging Library.

Comment: k. after registering how will i get the message from server.Actually my piece of code like this,  @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

Comment: String message = intent.getStringExtra("data");
        generateNotification(context, message);  And also its needed change of code on server side too.  Ask your web developer to do so.

Comment: still i am lacking about this. i written the client code like this String message = intent.getStringExtra("data"); generateNotification(context, message); ,please can you send the server code for belongs to this?

Comment: Hi Trivedi,very thanks to guided me.Actually i got what i want in Gcm.